# Python Delete not working

Tags: python, mysql

***I don't know Syntax Error. and if can't delete then rollback data.maybe you can advise me***

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import mysql.connector

conn= mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',user='user',passwd='pwd',db='dest')
cursor = conn.cursor()

sql =  "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 > "%d" % (60)
try:
        try:
                cursor.execute(sql)
                conn.commit()
        except:
                conn.rollback()
except:
        print "Error connect"

if conn:
        conn.close()
```

Comment: What is the actual problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a syntax error in sql =.
It should be like.

```
sql = "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 > '%d' "% (60)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If i want to delete several table. How to delete several tables.

Comment: Try to use like this.

DROP TABLE table1, table2, table3

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry,i want to delete table1(row1)=step1,table2(row1)=step2,table3(row1)=step3. so delete together but process delete error step any. such as delete step1=sucess step2=sucess but step3 error if error give rollback data. can you advise and thank you everything

Answer (score -2):

To drop 3 tables, Try to use like this.

```
DROP TABLE table1, table2, table3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry,i want to delete table1(row1)=step1,table2(row1)=step2,table3(row1)=step3. so delete together but process delete error step any. such as delete step1=sucess step2=sucess but step3 error if error give rollback data. can you advise and thank you everything

Comment: Then try to use them in different lines and commit () after each step. There will be no rollback for all the steps. Hope this helps.

Comment: i will try thx.

Comment: Bro! i can chat private with you ?. I have question many. facebook?

Comment: i has code Python `sql = "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 = 1"`
want to delete 1row. data in mysql user1 has data user1(INT,PK),ipadd,user2,sipadd. then i need to delete but don't work